# Expansion in Linux

Tags: linux, shell

I was reading below tutorial

http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0080.php

It says about double quotes:

> Double Quotes
>
> The first type of quoting we will look at is double quotes. 
>       If you place text inside double quotes, all the special characters used by the shell
>       lose their special meaning and are treated as ordinary characters. The exceptions are “$”,
>        “\” (backslash), and “`” (back- quote). This means that word-splitting, pathname expansion, 
>       tilde expansion, and brace expansion are suppressed, but parameter expansion, 
>       arithmetic expansion, and command substitution are still carried out.

And about single quotes:

> Single Quotes
>
> If you need to suppress all expansions, you use single quotes.

It does explain, with `ls` why does only `*.txt` works not `"*.txt"` or `'*.txt'`

```
 $ ls -l *.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 Gaurav None  8893 Apr 17 06:25 BigText.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Gaurav None 54376 Apr 18 12:32 File.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 Gaurav None   371 Apr 23 21:04 Filelist.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Gaurav None 54386 Apr 18 12:28 FileOld.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 Gaurav None  1163 Apr 17 06:19 Read.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 Gaurav None   651 Apr 24 06:28 temp.txt


$ ls -l "*.txt"
ls: cannot access *.txt: No such file or directory
$ ls -l '*.txt'
ls: cannot access *.txt: No such file or directory
```

My question is that, with `find or grep` why does `"*.txt", '*.txt'` both provide expansion: (In fact `*.txt` did not provide any expansion for name as opposed with `ls`)

e.g.

```
$ find . -name *.txt
find: paths must precede expression: File.txt
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]


$ find . -name "*.txt"
./BigText.txt
./File.txt
./Filelist.txt
./FileOld.txt
./Read.txt
./sample/BigText.txt
./sample/File.txt
./sample/FileOld.txt
./sample/Read.txt
./sample/temp.txt
./temp.txt


$ find . -name '*.txt'
./BigText.txt
./File.txt
./Filelist.txt
./FileOld.txt
./Read.txt
./sample/BigText.txt
./sample/File.txt
./sample/FileOld.txt
./sample/Read.txt
./sample/temp.txt
./temp.txt
```

Comment: Based on your outputs, expansion is handled by the shell correctly. `*` loses its meaning inside double quotes thus when passed as parameter to any command, will not be expanded. `find` expects a `pattern` after `-name` thus the need to use quote or the shell will expand the expression and cause syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` does its own expansion of the `*` – it does not need the shell to do it.

You need to be aware of what happens when you type a command in the shell (or when the shell executes a command from a script):

First, all the expansions are done *by the shell*, such as variable expansion (turns `$foo` into the value of `foo`), tilde expansion (turns `~` into the home directory path) and globbing (turns `*` into all matching files).

Then, after all that expansion is done, the expanded value is executed as a command.

When you invoke `find`, you actually do **not** want the shell to expand the `*` that you pass to `find` as part of a pattern, because the `find` command interprets the `*` by itself and uses it as a search pattern (as in `find <dir> -name '*.foo'`).

Comment: `find` uses the parameter after `-name` as a `regex`. Letting shell expand the parameters after `-name` causes syntax error.

Comment: Yes, which is why I wrote that you do want to protect the `*` from the shell when you use find.  BTW I think you're wrong about the regex.  `-name` does take a shell glob, not a regular expression.

Comment: I just checked the man page for `find`: `-name` does NOT take a regex.  If you want that, you have to use `-regex`

Comment: +1 You are right about it. I am mixing the `-name` and `-regex` but both requires protection from shell expansion.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `ls`, the shell expands the wildcards and provides multiple arguments to the command.

```
ls *.txt -> ls a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

In the case of `find`, the wildcards are passed to the command itself and it is responsible for expanding them, with [`glob(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) in the case of `-{,i}name`.

Answer (score 1):

`ls` relies on shell expansion, which means the shell itself, when it sees `*.txt`, replaces it with a list of all matching files in the current directory. Using quotes suppresses shell expansion.

You can see shell expansion with `echo`. Try:

```
echo '*.txt'
echo "*.txt"
echo *.txt
```